# Do android devices come with google play installed?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Apologies if this is a ridiculously simple question, but as someone who does not own a mobile phone, but has to develop for them I have to ask.

Currently developing an app that requires access to gMaps among other google play services. As far as I know any real Android i've tested it on, has been fine, I have error handling in place if the users device does *not* have google play, telling them it is needed.

Is it worth looking into a better way to handle this (i.e auto download everything required) or do all Androids phone ship with Play and it will be present unless purposely uninstalled by the user?

If that is not the case, any suggestions on the best way to handle such an issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> As far as I know any real Android i've tested it on, has been fine

If you plan on distributing your app through the Play Store, then if your app is installed through the Play Store, the device will have Play Services (though possibly not the latest-and-greatest version).

If you plan on distributing your app by other means, there is no guarantee that the device will have Play Services.

I do not know what you consider a "real Android" to be. Certainly, Chinese users of devices from Huawei, Xiaomi, and others would consider theirs to be "real", as would users of devices like the Amazon Fire series. Those devices do not ship with the Play Store or Play Services.

> auto download everything required

You have no way of downloading Play Services on a device that lacks it, short of software piracy.

> If that is not the case, any suggestions on the best way to handle such an issue would be appreciated.

Either:

- Do not use Play Services and instead use alternatives that work everywhere (e.g., OpenStreetMap), or
- Have multiple flavors of your project, where you use different solutions based on distribution channel (e.g., Maps V2 for Google Play devices, OpenStreetMap for others), or
- Only distribute through the Play Store, in which case your exception handling should be sufficient for the handful of people who try using some pirated copy of your app

IOW, your product needs to match your distribution channel, where you are depending on things that in turn depend upon the distribution channel.

Comment: By real devices I mean physical machines, not emulators :) I mean no offence to our Chinese friends. I will take this all on board and start looking into OpenStreetMap for a separate flavour (better to be safe than sorry)

Comment: @Aphire: Only do that if you plan on distributing through a channel other than the Play Store. If you do not have any current plans to do so, but might in the future, you might settle for just trying to isolate the Maps V2-dependent code, to make it easier for some future product flavor to replace that code with something else.

Comment: Well I think we plan to distribute a version for testing first (not via Play), of which I may use OpenStreet just to be safe, or just ensure the test group have Play. Not sure how much interaction I will have with the testers, so might just be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play, for Android phones, does come with most of them standard. The "standard" ones come from stores like Verizon, and usually contain the device's Android version changed a little bit by the company they are being sold by.

That being said, if you're publishing your app on the Play Store, then you really shouldn't worry about them having Google Play (Services) or not.

Answer (score 1):

TBH if you distribute your app via Play Store, I don't see much chance that the device has no Google Play (services) installed during runtime.

On other hand if the user has no Play Store I don't think you can auto-install anything, let alone official Google app, to someone's device without prompting them for permission.

**Off topic:** You develop mobile apps without having at least few test devices? O.o Just be careful, if it runs smoothly in emulator, it does not guarantee a smooth run on an actual device.

Comment: I do have some test devices :P, thats what I mean by "real androids". I just don't own one. :)

Comment: ahhh OK, misunderstood :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering about third party services that allow people to download any app from Google Play through another service, I wouldn't worry about those, because it's hard to tell how authentic/official those services are, anyway. They may be offering versions of your app with malware/spyware/adware and such added on for all you know. I would just assume your users have Google Play (if you're only purposefully offering it on Google Play) and not worry about it—or else state that Google Play is a requirement for your app.

If that's not what you were asking, here's an answer to another interpretation of your question:

Google Play can only be installed legally by the manufacturer (although it can be installed illegally by anyone, last I checked).

There are lots of Android devices that don't come with Google Play installed, but the popular, more expensive devices that a lot of people use, should have it installed. Some of the less expensive and/or less-known ones will have it, too (but don't count on it; and don't count on it being legally installed where it exists 100% of the time). I think Google has a list of authorized devices, if you're really curious which ones have it legally. I'm not sure if it's 100% up-to-date.

Something you should really want to know, though, is that Amazon's Kindle Fire devices do not have Google Play, but they are still technically Android devices capable of running Android apps (although the OS has been adapted to be a little different than the standard Android). They use the Amazon Appstore instead. It can easily be installed on other Android devices, whether or not they have Google Play (so, it's not just a Kindle Fire thing, but it's a useful store for anyone who doesn't have Google Play).

I personally recommend designing your app to work with both Google Play and the Amazon appstore, in order to allow anyone to use your app—or at the very least, offer the apk independent of an appstore on your personal website (whether you sell it there or give it away free, it doesn't matter; people need a way to access it if they don't have Google Play—if it works without Google Play, anyway).

I've personally found that most of the Android devices I've wanted to purchase did not have Google Play pre-installed. I haven't been looking at high-end devices, though (like the Nexus 7, Galaxy tablet or whatever).

It seems like more phones probably have it pre-installed than tablets, though. Tracfones and stuff like that often have it (although I don't recommend those if you're looking for an Android device with Google Play, even though they may have it).

You can design your app to require Google Play (a lot of apps do), and rely on other Google apps—but it's going to lock you into the Google environment, and exclude people outside of it. Whether you like that enough for your purposes or not is up to you, though.

If you don't have any alternative apps to the Google apps you want to use (Gmaps, etc.) then you might as well keep up the Google Play requirement (you won't normally find regular Google apps on other appstores). If you do have alternatives that are available on the Amazon appstore (or other such), then you might want to try those out and see if they work. So yeah, make sure whatever dependencies your app has are available to the user. They can't automatically download stuff that isn't on their appstore, and they can't use Google Play (and thus official Google apps) if they don't have it.

But again, I don't want to make it sound like you shouldn't use Google Play and Google apps. They may or may not be the only things currently available that are suitable for your purposes. You'd have to research other apps to be sure. If what you need isn't there, you may want to check again in the future, periodically, for new apps that fit your purposes (maybe once every year or two).